# Big O - Checking Method and then returning method vs assigning method to variable and returning variable?

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, runtime, big-o

Big O - Checking Method and then returning method vs assigning method to variable and returning variable?

Is there a different in runtime between A and B. From what I can see, I am assigning peek to a variable in the first and reusing it (O(n)). In the second, I am running peek() twice which would make it slower (O(n^2)). Am I correct?

A:

```
Object peek = stack.peek();
if (peek != null) {
    return peek;
}

else {
    return null;
}
```

B:

```
if (stack.peek() != null) {
    return stack.peek();
}

else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In classic implementation of stack Peek operation usually takes O(1) so both of your methods would be O(1). Even if you have some unordinary stack implementation which uses O(N) operations for Peek you will still get same complexities for both methods. It will be O(N) for A and O(N)+O(N)=O(N) for B.

Comment: Oops yeah, I don't know why I said n. Would you typically go with method A since it's half the time (despite same overall runtime)?

Comment: For sure. I would go with A.

Comment: Thanks! Question... Does assigning to a variable increase memory usage over just running the same method twice? Therefore method A is faster runtime, but more memory versus B being slower runtime and less memory? Still new to Big O...

Comment: If we are speaking in terms of classic Big-O model: both methods are identical. Classic Big-O model counts single calls/assignments as constants i.e. O(1).

Comment: Ah yeah, haha! Does the variable in method A have any memory implication though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the same operation twice instead of once doubles the runtime. This is treated as a "constant multiplier" in asymptotic complexity analysis, and ignored.

Comment: Ah, so B would O(2n) -> O(n)... Technically method A is faster though, right?

Comment: "technically faster" does not figure into complexity analysis. But yes, not doing unneccessary work is faster.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but does assigning to a variable increase memory usage over just running the same method twice? Therefore method A is faster runtime, but more memory versus B being slower runtime and less memory? Still new to Big O...